# Как показать элементы при событии React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Имеется вот такой React компонент, в который импортирован компонент `WorkItem`.

При завершении анимации `(смотреть onTransitionEnd)` нужно показать эти компоненты `WorkItem`, как это возможно сделать?

```js
import React from 'react';
import Slider from "react-slick";

import WorkItem from '../WorkItem';

class PortfolioSectionPanel extends React.Component {

    constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = {
            works: [
                {
                    type: 'Some',
                    link: 'some',
                },
                {
                    type: 'Some1',
                    link: 'some1',
                },
                {
                    type: 'Some',
                    link: 'some',
                },
                {
                    type: 'Some1',
                    link: 'some1',
                },
                {
                    type: 'Some',
                    link: 'some',
                },
                {
                    type: 'Some',
                    link: 'some',
                },
            ]
        }

        this.showWorks = () => {
            let {works} = this.state;

            const angleRad = 360 / works.length * 0.017; //Частота кругов в радианах
            const bg = document.getElementById('portfolio-panel-disk');
            let radius;
            if(bg) {
                radius = parseInt(getComputedStyle(bg).width) / 2 * 20;
            }

            let workItems = works.map((currentValue, index) => {
                return <WorkItem 
                        type={currentValue.type} 
                        link={currentValue.type} 
                        key={index} 
                        leftOffset={radius - radius * Math.cos(angleRad * index)}
                        topOffset={radius - radius * Math.sin(angleRad * index)}  />
            })

            return workItems
        }

    }
    
    render() {
   
        return(

            <div className={this.props.freshClass}>
                <div className={this.props.classForBg} onTransitionEnd={this.showWorks} >
                    <div className='portfolio-panel-disk' id='portfolio-panel-disk'>
                        {workItems}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
    

export default PortfolioSectionPanel;
```

Comment: чет у вас все не так, почему `showWorks` возвращает массив? С чего вы взяли, что переменная `workItems` доступна в ф-ции `render`?

Comment: @ThisMan, я новичок в React. Функция showWorks возвращает массив элементов, которые нужно вывести, как нужно делать?

Comment: @uzi_no_uzi почитать учебник какой-нибудь по js и обратить внимание на главу с областями видимости

Answer (score 0):

Значение workItems не определено в методе render.

```
render() {
  const workItems = this.showWorks(); 

  return (
          <div className={this.props.freshClass}>
                <div className={this.props.classForBg} onTransitionEnd={this.showWorks} >
                    <div className='portfolio-panel-disk' id='portfolio-panel-disk'>
                        {workItems}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
}
```

Пример на sandbox https://codesandbox.io/embed/polished-glade-jkz5d